# The doskey command separator produces blank lines

Tags: cmd, macros, command-line-interface, alias, doskey

The `doskey` command separator (`$T`) generates a blank line when the command produces no output.

```
C:\> set "a="                                                    

C:\> set "b="                                                    

C:\> doskey test=set "a=foo" $T set "b=bar" $T echo ^%a^% ^%b^%

C:\> test                                                      

C:\>                                                           
C:\> foo bar
```

Note the blank line after issuing `test`, which affects readability.

There is a well-known `^?` alternative to `$T`, which does not add blanks, but the new command does not inherits environment variables.

```
C:\> set "a="                                                    

C:\> set "b="                                                    

C:\> doskey test=set "a=foo" ^& set "b=bar" ^& echo ^%a^% ^%b^%

C:\> test                                                      
%a% %b%
```

There are no blanks here, anyway `set` is ineffective after starting a new command.

How can I remove the blank lines?

*Update:* 
Removed "creates a separate process" line as it was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `$T` and `^&` is who handles the execution of the different commands.

When `$T` is used, `doskey` knows there is more than one command and it is itself who serially executes the commands in the current `cmd` instance, with the blank lines and prompt lines as a side effect.

When `^&` is used, `doskey` (who is checking the `$` prefixed characters) only sees a character without any special meaning. When the macro is invoked, `doskey` only executes one command (the full line) and is the `cmd` parser who now sees the concatenated commands and handles the serial execution, this time without additional lines.

The indicated *"... it creates a separate process not inheriting environment variables."* is not correct. There is no additional process. What you see is the usual variable expansion *"problem"*. Variable read operations are removed from the line at parse time to generate the final command to execute. You can not change a variable in a line and retrieve the changed value from the same line in a later command because the read operation was replaced while parsing, before starting the execution that will change the variable. (Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177832/2861476))

So, now, instead of one, we have two problems to solve. The variable expansion in the `^&` case and the additional lines in the `$T` case.

If delayed expansion is not enabled, we can not enable it from the current `cmd` instance while in command line context (only inside batch files), so, to solve the problem we need to force an additional parse of the line to force retrieval of the changed value. We can use the `call` command before the `echo`

```dos
doskey test=set "a=foo" ^& set "b=bar" ^& call echo ^%a^% ^%b^%
```

But it is easier to solve the other problem. The empty and prompt lines are a simply `echo` problem

```dos
doskey test=echo off $t set "a=foo" $t set "b=bar" $t echo ^%a^% ^%b^% $t echo on
```

Just turn `echo off` at the start and `on` at the end.

Comment: @antonio, just to be precise, the `does not inherit environment variables` is also not correct. 1) not existing a new process there is nothing to inherit 2) variables are not echoed, but they are properly initialized, you can replace the `echo ^%a^% ^%b^%` with a `set` command and see them, simply you can not directly retrieve their value.